# Python uncaught exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I've got two programs written in Python2 running on Raspberry Pi, but my question strictly concerns Python. First program detects temperature and prints its value on a 16x2 LCD, while the second one is controlled by an IR remote which is used for toggling LEDs. Both programs use similar try/except mechanism, run in an infinite loop and terminate by `CTRL+C`. The first one behaves as expected (gives `^CBye!`):

```
import os
import glob
import time
from RPi import GPIO
from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp_c():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = round(int(temp_string) / 1000.0, 2)
        temp_c = "%.2f" % temp_c
        return temp_c

def read_temp_f():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_f = round((int(temp_string) / 1000.0) * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, 2)
        temp_f = "%.2f" % temp_f
        return temp_f

try:
    lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2, pin_rs=38, pin_e=40, pins_data=[31,33,35,37], numbering_mode=GPIO.BOARD)

    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'
    while True:
        lcd.cursor_pos = (0, 0)
        lcd.write_string(unicode("Temp: " + read_temp_c() + unichr(223) + "C"))
        lcd.cursor_pos = (1, 0)
        lcd.write_string(unicode("Temp: " + read_temp_f() + unichr(223) + "F"))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\nBye!"
except:
    print "Error... aborting\n"
finally:
    lcd.close(clear=True)
    #GPIO.cleanup()
```

whereas the other one is not:

```
import lirc
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import wiringpi

#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi.pinMode(23, 1)
wiringpi.pinMode(24, 1)
wiringpi.pinMode(25, 1)
sockid = lirc.init("ir_leds")
try:
    while True:
        diodeID = int(lirc.nextcode()[0])
        if diodeID == 1:
#            GPIO.output(23, not GPIO.input(23))
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(23, not wiringpi.digitalRead(23))
        elif diodeID == 2:
#            GPIO.output(24, not GPIO.input(24))
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(24, not wiringpi.digitalRead(24))
        elif diodeID == 3:
#            GPIO.output(25, not GPIO.input(25))
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(25, not wiringpi.digitalRead(25))
        else:
            raise Exception()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\nBye!"
except:
    print "Error... aborting"
finally:
    lirc.deinit()
#    GPIO.output(23, 0)
#    GPIO.output(24, 0)
#    GPIO.output(25, 0)
#    GPIO.cleanup()
    wiringpi.digitalWrite(23, 0)
    wiringpi.digitalWrite(24, 0)
    wiringpi.digitalWrite(25, 0)
    wiringpi.pinMode(23, 0)
    wiringpi.pinMode(24, 0)
    wiringpi.pinMode(25, 0)
```

Terminating this one with `CTRL+C` will result in:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "ir_leds.py", line 15, in <module>
    diodeID = int(lirc.nextcode()[0])
KeyboardInterrupt
```

However, `finally` blocks seem to run correctly in both cases. What is the reason of this behaviour and how can I handle exceptions correctly in this case?

Comment: So you don't get "Bye!" or "Error... aborting"?

Comment: Nope, neither of them

Comment: It's possible `lirc.nextcode` is catching the KeyboardInterrupt, but I don't know why it would do that and that would probably mean Ctrl-C would get through sometimes. Looking at the code, I see no reason why it wouldn't work how you expect it to, so I blame the libraries.

Comment: @Beefster That would make sense, but I don't see anything in [`nextcode()`](https://github.com/tompreston/python-lirc/blob/master/lirc/lirc.pyx#L218) that would suggest that being the case.

Comment: I'd say the chances are the code you shared is not consistent with the code you are running. That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: Ok then, I'm attaching full code ran by me. I've just edited it in the main post.